# How to send an image from Next.js to Strapi using Fetch API?

Tags: javascript, next.js, fetch-api, strapi

I have this collection type in Strapi:
[image]

I need to set banner from Strapi endpoint in Next.js.

I tried using this API `http://localhost:1337/api/upload`.
Image upload successfuly but image not set in my user banner field. Image only goes to Strapi media library.

```
async function handalBannerUpload(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    const formdata = new FormData();

    formdata.append("files",file[0]);
    formdata.append("field","banner");
    formdata.append("refid",29);
    formdata.append("ref","plugin::users-permissions.user");

    // for (const value of formdata.values()) {
    //   console.log({value});
    // }

    const res = await fetch("http://localhost:1337/api/upload",{
      method:"POST",
      headers: {
        // 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        Authorization: apiKey,
      },
      body: {
        files: JSON.stringify(formdata.get('files')),
        field: "banner",
        refid: data?.id,
        ref: "plugin::users-permissions.user",
      }
      // body: formdata
    })

    const dataRes = await res.json();

    console.log(dataRes);
    
  }
```